# open-source (doesn't need to be free) software or component for recurring scheduling of resources (like conference rooms)

Tags: scheduled-tasks, resource-scheduling

I'm looking for a project or 3rd party component that allows redcurrant reservations of a resource.

For example a meeting that needs to be held in meeting room A, only when it's not occupied, every Thursday.  The meeting is one hour long, and depending on meeting room availability can start between 9am and 4pm.

Any pointers to software that approaches this functionality would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpSchedule should help out with that.

http://www.php.brickhost.com/faq.php